# running go return panic: internal error: missing go version in modload.Requirements

Tags: macos, go

I just installed go on my mac(arm) using the below command:

```
brew install go
```

And then I created a new project using Goland IDE. When I run using `go run hello.go` it return the bellow error:

```
panic: go: internal error: missing go root module

goroutine 1 [running]:
cmd/go/internal/modload.mustHaveGoRoot(...)
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.1/libexec/src/cmd/go/internal/modload/buildlist.go:104
cmd/go/internal/modload.newRequirements(0xe0?, {0x14000080360?, 0x100f984e0?, 0x1400000e1f8?}, 0x120?)
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.1/libexec/src/cmd/go/internal/modload/buildlist.go:118 +0x59c
cmd/go/internal/modload.updatePrunedRoots({0x10106daf0, 0x1014511e0}, 0x14000196600, 0x140000202d0, {0x0, 0x0, 0x14000196600?}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x14000192c80?}, ...)
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.1/libexec/src/cmd/go/internal/modload/buildlist.go:1236 +0x9bc
cmd/go/internal/modload.updateRoots({0x10106daf0?, 0x1014511e0?}, 0x0?, 0x140000620d8?, {0x0?, 0x2?, 0x140000620d8?}, {0x0?, 0x14000075700?, 0x140000620e8?}, ...)
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.1/libexec/src/cmd/go/internal/modload/buildlist.go:796 +0x7c
cmd/go/internal/modload.loadModFile({0x10106daf0, 0x1014511e0}, 0x0)
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.1/libexec/src/cmd/go/internal/modload/init.go:964 +0x12cc
cmd/go/internal/modload.LoadModFile({0x10106daf0?, 0x1014511e0?})
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.1/libexec/src/cmd/go/internal/modload/init.go:793 +0x28
cmd/go/internal/modcmd.runDownload({0x10106daf0, 0x1014511e0}, 0x1400002c558?, {0x140000200e0, 0x0, 0x0})
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.1/libexec/src/cmd/go/internal/modcmd/download.go:120 +0x74
main.invoke(0x1013dcd00, {0x140000200c0, 0x3, 0x3})
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.1/libexec/src/cmd/go/main.go:257 +0x4d8
main.main()
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.22.1/libexec/src/cmd/go/main.go:175 +0x688
```

I attempted to manually set GOROOT or GOPATH, but the error persists. The error message either reads "missing go version in modload.Requirements" or "missing go root module."

Here is my hello.go script:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello, world!")
}
```

and here is my `go.mod` :

```
module go

go 1.22
```

Comment: You should neither install Go via brew nor use filename arguments to go run.

Comment: @Volker Why not? Using brew I can auto update the go version.

Comment: and for use filename argument, yes, it's just for demo purpose, usually I just use run button in my Goland IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises from creating a Goland project with a directory name "go" resulting in the generated module also named "go". To resolve this, I removed the `go.mod` file and executed `go mod init hello`, which successfully resolved the problem.

So, the solution is straightforward: rename the module to avoid using reserved keywords like "go". This simple adjustment resolves the issue.

```
module go // <-- rename this to other name

go 1.22
```